# How to make my theme styling apply to all CMS pages?

Tags: magento2

How could I achieve this?

All headers, paragraphs, etc. on all CMS pages having the same styling if my theme is being used.

I could not find an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to presume you are using Blank or Luma as a parent theme and you're using LESS and compiling via the built-in Magento methods. If you are not please let me know as the answer may differ dependant on your setup.

You need to extend your parent theme's CMS styling and target the CMS pages only, so if you don't already have this file create it:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Cms/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Then add your code, I've added an example with some media queries below. Because of the `.cms-page-view` it will only target CMS pages, it's probably wise to add in another selector so you don't affect elements in the header/footer.

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .cms-page-view {
        p,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}


//
//  Mobile
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .cms-page-view {
        p,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}


//
//  Tablet
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .cms-page-view {
        p,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}



//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
    .cms-page-view {
        p,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3 {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to delete `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static/frontend` and then clear your caches and possibly run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` dependant on your setup.

Comment: What if I use this theme as my parent theme? If all magento modules are under vendor/ folder does that change anything? https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass

Comment: Not really as long as you use Sass and the correct mixins.